# Jmeter logging for API URL+Request+ResponseCode+ResponseBody in csv

Tags: javascript, csv, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I like to save the following parameters in a CSV file in single line for HTTP REST call in Jmeter.
Endpoint URL, request body, request header, response code, response body . could someone help with JS code or groovy code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show us where you're stuck? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think you will be able to save request and response "in single line" because:

   - for sure it will have [line breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)
   - most probably it will have [delimiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) (i.e. CSV stands for "comma-separated values" and if your response will contain a comma - it will create another "column")
2. If you're going to use [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for this it can be done, but the correct work is guaranteed only for a one thread (virtual user), if you have more than 1 user concurrently writing the data into the same file you'll face the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) resulting in data corruption or loss

So I would recommend considering using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) which provides full freedom to choose what to store, where to store and it "flushes" the metrics periodically in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Thanks @Dmiri T
This helps!